# Перебор строки в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Есть задача. Нужно проверить если количество элементов в строке четное, то разбить ее на подстроки по 2 элемента в каждой, если строка содержит нечетное количество символов, она должна заменить отсутствующий второй символ последней пары подчеркиванием ('_').

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем отличие 1 кода от 1? Почему 1 работает, а 1 нет.

`1:`

```
def solution(s):
    n = 2
    s = [s[index : index + n] for index in range(0, len(s), n)]
    return s

print(solution('abcd')) # здесь только получаю `ab`, `cd` не видит
```

`2:`

```
def solution(s):
    n = 2
    for i in range(0,len(s),n):
        s = [s[i:i+n]]
        return s

print(solution('abcd'))
```

но тут еще не получается сделать проверку на нечетность.

Comment: `" если нет, то заменить"` - что заменить и на что заменить?

Comment: @Zhihar, обновил

Comment: и что, первый код на что-то заменяет?

Comment: @splash58 нет, там просто проверка

Comment: если вы про свой код №2 - потому что `return s` внутри `for` - т.е. он у вас срабатывает только при первом выделении 2х букв, кроме того вы не увеличиваете массив результатов своим `s = s[...]` да и вообще менять итерационный объект по которому вы двигаетесь в цикле - очень плохо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def solution(text):
    if len(text) % 2 != 0:
        text = text + "_"
    return [text[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(text), 2)]

print(solution('abcd'))
print(solution('abcde'))
```

можно и в 1 строку:

```
def solution(text):
    return [((text + "_") if len(text) % 2 else text)[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len((text + "_") if len(text) % 2 else text), 2)]
```

Comment: не так сработало почему-то, он заменяет первый элемент и через него, даже если четное кол-во

Comment: а... вы в задаче условие изменили - сейчас подумаю как тогда должно выглядеть должно

Comment: изменил код на тот, который вам нужен

Comment: при нечетносом кол-ве символов он не разбивает также как если бы при четном, просто добавляется `_` в конец. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: еще раз проверьте - наверное обновление кода было позже, чем вы посмотрели

Comment: а... понял - return зря поставил - исправил код

Comment: окей, спасибо. Я все равно не понимаю, почему когда переписываю, то только `ab` получаю, вместо `[ab],[cd]`:      `for i in range(0, len(text), 2):
      return [text[i:i+2]] ` # моя запись не работает
        `return [text[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(text), 2)]` # ваша запись работает

Comment: если вы про свой код - потому что `return` внутри `for` - т.е. он у вас срабатывает только при первом выделении 2х букв

Comment: но без `return` почему-то также, в чем может причина интересно? Спасибо за помощь кстати! Отметил:)

Comment: потому что вы меняете строку внутри цикла по той же строке, а так делать нельзя! или надо этот процесс очень жестко контролировать

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться функцией zip, добавив во второй срез подчеркивание. Оно попадет в результат только при нечетной длине

```
 def solution(s):
    return [a+b for a,b in zip(s[::2], s[1::2]+'_')]
print(solution('abcde'))
```

Comment: кажется здесь не хватает  `''.join([a,b])`

Comment: @SergFSM да, возможно - я этого не понял из вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Починить ваш второй код (без проверки на четность) можно так:

```
def solution(s):
    n = 2
    res = []
    for i in range(0,len(s),n):
        res += [s[i:i+n]]
    return res
```

Ну и в коллекцию к уже предложенным решениям еще одно, рекурсивное. Вам, скорее всего, такое не нужно, но как вариант, думаю, пойдет:

```
solution = lambda s: [s[:2]] + solution(s[2:]) if len(s)>1 else (s and [s+'_'] or [])

print(solution('abcde'))  # ['ab', 'cd', 'e_']
```